# Android on Asus Fonepad 7 report to be armeabi-v7a even if it's an X86

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my app I check the CPU from **Build.CPU_ABI** and if the CPU is **X86** ask the user to download the correct package with X86 libraries bundled.

But today I got an Asus Fonepad 7 with an Intel CPU, but surprisingly the **Build.CPU_ABI** is **armeabi-v7a** instead of **X86**. I read somewhere that because many developers don't bundle **X86** native libraries in their apps, Asus has used an ARM-X86 translator so the app think is running on an **Arm** device. More surprisingly even if **X86** libraries are bundled it still loads **Arm** libraries.

I believe code translation reduce performance dramatically. So is there any way to determine the real CPU arch? And after that force X86 libraries to be loaded instead of Arm?

------ EDIT --------

**When I removed the armeabi-v7a folder from the package **Build.CPU_ABI** become X86 and now it loads the X86 codes.**

I checked out /proc/cpuinfo, the only thing which is clear is it packs an Intel CPU. So is it safe to consider the CPU an X86 if intel word appear in cpuinfo?

And the only option is to have two different APKs, one for arm another for X86. because if all binaries are in the same APK file, Arm binaries are loaded no matter what!

This is /proc/cpuinfo content:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 90
model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU   4000  @ 1.00GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x27
cpu MHz     : 1833.000
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms
bogomips    : 1996.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 90
model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU   4000  @ 1.00GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x27
cpu MHz     : 1833.000
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms
bogomips    : 1996.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 90
model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU   4000  @ 1.00GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x27
cpu MHz     : 1833.000
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms
bogomips    : 1996.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 90
model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU   4000  @ 1.00GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x27
cpu MHz     : 1833.000
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms
bogomips    : 1996.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 1):

you could read /proc/cpuinfo

```
➜  ~  adb shell
shell@android:/ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo                                            
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
```

Comment: Please check my update! The only thing related to an X86 cpu in cpuinfo file is intel word. Is it safe to consider any device with an intel word in it's cpuinfo file an X86 cpu?

Comment: @ChrisStratton how about checking if ARMv7 word doesn't exist in cpuinfo file?

Comment: @Ali: sounds good ( checking for Intel ) - but I would first try if your device can still handle x86 code with the changes applied - perhaps they destroyed this path so you do not need to figure out this detail in the first place ..

Comment: How to check if device can handle x86 code when it reports to be an ARM and load ARM binaries even if X86 binaries are packed?

Comment: Try it out - I do not own such a crippled device - would not even care for a bad performance on something like this - they deserve this ...-)

Comment: :)) It's a popular device as much as I know as it's so cheap. It really shocked me when I logged Build.CPU_ABI and see armeabi-v7 although I knew it has an Intel CPU and shocked me more when I removed armeabi-v7 folder and it became X86 :)) I blame Intel more by selling it's stupid X86 cpu so cheap.

Comment: _"how about checking if ARMv7 word doesn't exist"_ That doesn't sound like a particularly good idea, since an ARM processor isn't necessarily based on the ARMv7 architecture. You could combine a check for "Intel" in the model name with checking various flag names like "mmx", "sse2", and "tsc" that also would suggest an x86 CPU.

Answer (score 1):

```
getprop | grep -i cpu
```

This will tell you all of the available abis... getprop, in general, is useful for getting more gritty sysinfo.